# End subsubsection or section

Tags: sections-paragraphs

Good morning, my new problem is very simple, but i don't understand exactly how to fix it. I have a

```
\section{Name of my section}
```

After, I added

```
\subsection{name of my new subsection}
```

Finally, I added

```
\subsubsection{name of my new subsubsection}
```

When i finish to write my subsubsection, this seems continued on next page, but this page is empty as it should be. [image]

In this case if i cut subsubsection returns to normal.
I have the same problem in another point of my text but this doesn't depend on of subsubsection. Can I fix this type of problem ? 
This is the structured of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[ansinew,latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\oddsidemargin=30pt \evensidemargin=20pt%impostano i margini
\hyphenation{sil-la-ba-zio-ne pa-ren-te-si}



\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \#1}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

\linespread{1.3}                        

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}                      
\thispagestyle{empty}                   %elimina il numero della pagina
\topmargin=6.5cm                        
\raggedleft                             %incolonna la scrittura a destra
\large                                  %aumenta la grandezza del carattere
                                    %   a 14pt
\em                                     %emfatizza (corsivo) il carattere


\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}                   %serve per mettere i numeri romani
\input{introduzione}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\tableofcontents                      
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries
INDICE}}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\listoffigures                        
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\listoftables                           %crea l'elenco delle tabelle

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\definecolor{mediumblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.8}
\input{primocapitolo}
\input{secondocapitolo}
\input{terzocapitolo}
\input{quartocapitolo}
\input{quintocapitolo}

\chapter*{Conclusioni}

\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries
CONCLUSIONI}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries
CONCLUSIONI}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%aggiunge la voce Conclusioni
                                    %   nell'indice
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusioni} Queste sono le
conclusioni.\\
Conclusioni.

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter \ \#1}{}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\appendix                               %imposta le appendici
\chapter{Prima Appendice}               %crea l'appendice
In questa Appendice non si \`e utilizzato il comando:\\
\verb'\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}', ed infatti
l'ultima pagina 8 ha l'intestazione con il numero di pagina in
alto.

\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thechapter \:Prima Appendice}]
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\chapter{Seconda Appendice}             
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thechapter \:Seconda Appendice}]
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\begin{thebibliography}{90}             %crea l'ambiente bibliografia
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries
\thepage}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}

\bibitem{K1} Lei Deng; Gao, J.;Vuppalapati, C., Building a Big Data     Analytics Service Framework for Mobile Advertising and Marketing, in 'Big Data Computing Service and Applications (BigDataService), 2015 IEEE First International Conference on', marzo 2015.

\end{thebibliography}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\chapter*{Ringraziamenti}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Ringraziamenti
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ans what follows to end of the your `\subsubsection{...}`? To see, what is your problem, we need an Minimal Working Example, i.e. small, complete document, which can be compiled and will show your problem.

Comment: I'm using a template of my Univerity. Next follow new chapter (Conclusion)

Comment: If you give us a small document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that reproduces the problem, we will be able to help you.  Otherwise, there isn't much we can do.

Comment: ok, I edit my question

Comment: @AntonioFaienza, it seems that your text before chapter is ended on odd page and chapter always start on odd page too, so LaTeX need to insert one empty (even) page.

Comment: @Zarko can i fix this ? I must add same option ??

Comment: Please fix your MWE. There are undefined control sequences (I guess some packages are missing) and `\:` are for math mode. If you are missing a space in your header, try `~`.

Comment: @AntonioFaienza,  it seems that there is nothing to fix! This is intentional (I guessing) determined in document class of your university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer but more extended comment.  I try to cleanup your MWE (which is, sorry for harsh word: awful). Read comments, that you will see, what is (to my opinion) wrong in your document design, and how to fix main weakness.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
    a4paper,
    openright,% <-- by this you request, 
              %     that chapters begin on odd (right) pages
              %     consequently if text before end on odd page, 
              %     the empty even page is introduced
    twoside]{report}
\usepackage[ansinew,latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\oddsidemargin=30pt % <-- instead this is better to use geometry packages
\evensidemargin=20pt%     for example \usepackage[inner=30pt,outer=20pt,
                    %                             top=20pt,bottom=20pt,
                    %                             includehead,includefoot]{geometry}  

\hyphenation{sil-la-ba-zio-ne pa-ren-te-si}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% <-- is missing
\pagestyle{fancy}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \#1}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}       % elimina il numero della pagina
\topmargin=6.5cm    % <-- wrong use, better is \vspace*{6.5cm}
\raggedleft             % incolonna la scrittura a destra
\large                  % aumenta la grandezza del carattere a 14pt
\em                 % obsolete, correct is \itshape 
                        % emfatizza (corsivo) il carattere

%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}% <-- wrong place,
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage    % <-- correct
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\pagenumbering{roman}                   %serve per mettere i numeri romani
\input{introduzione}
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\cleardoublepage    % <-- correct
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage    % <-- correct
% definitions below should be part of \pagestyle{fancy}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries INDICE}}
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage    % <-- correct
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\listoftables                           %crea l'elenco delle tabelle
\cleardoublepage    % <-- correct
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\definecolor{mediumblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.8}% wrong place, move to preamble
% are the following files chapters? if it so,than is better to use \include
\input{primocapitolo}   
\input{secondocapitolo}
\input{terzocapitolo}
\input{quartocapitolo}
\input{quintocapitolo}

\chapter*{Conclusioni}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusioni}

% this should be defined in \pagestyle{fancy}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries CONCLUSIONI}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
% \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries CONCLUSIONI}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%aggiunge la voce Conclusioni
                                    %   nell'indice
Queste sono le conclusioni.

Conclusioni.

% this should be defined in \pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter \ \#1}{}}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\appendix                               %imposta le appendici
\chapter{Prima Appendice}               %crea l'appendice
In questa Appendice non si \`e utilizzato il comando:\\
\verb'\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}', ed infatti
l'ultima pagina 8 ha l'intestazione con il numero di pagina in
alto.

%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thechapter \:Prima Appendice}]
%{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\chapter{Seconda Appendice}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thechapter \:Seconda Appendice}]
%{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}

\begin{thebibliography}{90}             %crea l'ambiente bibliografia
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thepage}}

\bibitem{K1} Lei Deng; Gao, J.;Vuppalapati, C., Building a Big Data     Analytics Service Framework for Mobile Advertising and Marketing, in 'Big Data Computing Service and Applications (BigDataService), 2015 IEEE First International Conference on', marzo 2015.

\end{thebibliography}
%\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Ringraziamenti}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Ringraziamenti
\end{document}
```

If you not like to start chapters on odd pages, than you need to write for document class something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
    a4paper,
    openany,% <-- by this you request, 
            %     that chapters begin on any pages
    twoside]{report}
```

Hopefully this will help you a bit. Good luck in writing of your thesis.

**Addendum:** I suggest you to read a book of Nicola Talbot: "How to write Ph.D. thesis" (http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] 
I replace this :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
```

with this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,oneside]{report}
```

if I want a blank page, I add:

```
clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
```

thank you all, Bye

Comment: This nothing change. See my answer below.